# Creating a List and maintaining integer value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I am new to python a bit.

I am trying to convert a dataframe to list after changing the datatype of a particular column to integer. The funny thing is when converted to list, the column still has float.

There are three columns in the dataframe, first two is float and I want the last to be integer, but it still comes as float.

If I change all to integer, then the list creates as integer.

```
0   1.53    3.13    0.0
1   0.58    2.83    0.0
2   0.28    2.69    0.0 
3   1.14    2.14    0.0
4   1.46    3.39    0.0
... ... ... ...
```

495  2.37    0.93    1.0
496  2.85    0.52    1.0
497  2.35    0.39    1.0
498  2.96    1.68    1.0
499  2.56    0.16    1.0

Above is the Dataframe.

Below is the last column converted

```
#convert last column to integer datatype
data[6] = data[6].astype(dtype ='int64')
display(data.dtypes)
```

The below is converting the dataframe to list.

```
#Turn DF to list
data_to_List = data.values.tolist()
data_to_List
```

#below is what is shown now.

```
[[1.53, 3.13, 0.0],
[0.58, 2.83, 0.0],
[0.28, 2.69, 0.0],
[1.14, 2.14, 0.0],
[3.54, 0.75, 1.0],
[3.04, 0.15, 1.0],
[2.49, 0.15, 1.0],
[2.27, 0.39, 1.0],
[3.65, 1.5, 1.0],
```

I want the last column to be just 0 or 1 and not 0.0 or 1.0

Comment: What are your column names? Is the last column name 6?

Comment: yes. 6 is last column

Comment: @TalhaTayyab, last column is 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct pandas is converting `int` to `float` when you use `data.values`

You can convert your `float` to `int` by using the below list comprehension:

```
data_to_List = [[x[0],x[1],int(x[2])] for x in data.values.tolist()]

print(data_to_List)

[[1.53, 3.13, 0],
 [0.58, 2.83, 0],
 [0.28, 2.69, 0],
 [1.14, 2.14, 0],
 [1.46, 3.39, 0]]
```